# Im Keep getting this error - Error: Not enough arguments (line 206)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

So I got this code from a LinkedIn profile and I just copypasted it in google app script.

```
    // Set-up

// 1. Replace `similarWeb_api_key` with your SimilarWeb API Key. 
// It will look like this on this file:
// const similarWeb_api_key = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
const similarWeb_api_key = "YOUR_API_KEY"

// 2. Save the Apps Script project
//
// 3. In your sheet, simply use the function =getTraffic({domain})



/**
 * Get Traffic Estimation from Domain.
 *
 * @param {string} companyName.
 * @return domainName.
 * @customfunction
 */

function getTraffic(domain) {



  var url = "https://api.similarweb.com/v1/similar-rank/"+domain+"/rank?api_key=" + similarWeb_api_key;
  var options = {
    "muteHttpExceptions": true,
  }
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  var responseCode = response.getResponseCode();
  var responseBody = response.getContentText();
  if (responseCode === 200) {
    Logger.log(response)
    Logger.log(JSON.parse(response).similar_rank.rank)
    similar_rank = JSON.parse(response).similar_rank.rank
    estimated_traffic = calculateTraffic(similar_rank)

    // display the results in 2 columns
var results = new Array(1);
let info = new Array(3);
info[0]=similar_rank
info[1]=estimated_traffic
results[0]=info

    return results


  } else {
    Logger.log(Utilities.formatString("Request failed for %s, got %d: %s", responseCode, responseBody));
    return false;
  }
}


function calculateTraffic(rank) {
  if (rank > 3079440) {
    return "Not Enough Traffic";
  }

  const data = [    [0, 86400000000],
    [20, 1400000000],
    [118, 200000000],
    [207, 113000000],
    [336, 85000000],
    [1068, 43000000],
    [1564, 26000000],
    [2818, 24000000],
    [3653, 11000000],
    [6000, 8000000],
    [13465, 3000000],
    [17734, 2000000],
    [22000, 4000000],
    [57316, 773400],
    [111510, 300000],
    [141314, 420000],
    [513447, 50000],
    [1539720, 27000],
    [3079440, 13000],
  ];

  let lowerBound = 0;
  let upperBound = 0;
  let lowerTraffic = 0;
  let upperTraffic = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i][0] >= rank) {
      upperBound = data[i][0];
      upperTraffic = data[i][1];
      lowerBound = data[i - 1][0];
      lowerTraffic = data[i - 1][1];
      break;
    }
  }

  if (rank === 5) {
    return (lowerTraffic + upperTraffic) / 4;
  } else if (rank === 10) {
    return (lowerTraffic + upperTraffic) / 2;
  } else if (rank === 15) {
    return (lowerTraffic + upperTraffic) * (3 / 4);
  } else {
    return lowerTraffic + (rank - lowerBound) * (upperTraffic - lowerTraffic) / (upperBound - lowerBound);
  }
}
```

I used the above code and did as the instruction guided me. But I keep getting the error - Error: Not enough arguments (line 206).

This code is for tracking website traffic. So it uses an API for a website.

[image: The ERROR]

I request someone to help me solve this.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you provide your current script? And also, unfortunately, I cannot know your "line 206". I apologize for this. In order to correctly understand your question, can I ask you about the detail of your current issue? First, I would like to correctly understand your current issue.

Comment: I have updated the post with the code. 
My issue is that it says line 206 and my code does not go that far. 
The ERROR makes zero sense to me.

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `My issue is that it says line 206 and my code does not go that far. The ERROR makes zero sense to me.`, when I saw your current script, I couldn't understand your `line 206` in your script. I apologize for this. Where is `line 206` in your showing script?

Comment: I don't know, that is the problem!

Basically when I enter - =getTraffic(A2) the code should run, but I am getting this error.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from `I don't know, that is the problem! Basically when I enter - =getTraffic(A2) the code should run, but I am getting this error.`, I couldn't still understand the error line of `line 206` in your showing script. In your error message, it seems that the error occurs at `line 206` in your script. But, your showing script has no 206 lines. So, in this case, it is required to know the error line. And, I think that only you can know it. So, I asked about the error line. I apologize for this.

Comment: If you cannot know it, for example, can you provide your sample Spreadsheet? Although I'm not sure your whole Google Apps Script project, I'm worried that for example, you might be using the methods which cannot be used with a custom function as the global variables, because your showing script has no `line 206`.

Comment: I agree with @Tanaike I think we need more information of your full script to better understand what is the issue on line 206.

Comment: I suspect there is something wrong with the `response` that `JSON.parse()` can not interpret.

Comment: @FernandoLara That is the full script! The problem is that I don't understand why it says LINE 206 when there is no line 206!

Comment: IMHO, without an API key and seeing the full `response` this item is impossible to debug.